# Comparing two arrays in ClickHouse rows

Tags: arrays, clickhouse, column-oriented

Any options to compare two arrays in ClickHouse?

There are two columns `colA` and `colB`, each contains an array.

If there any algorithm that compares arrays in `colA` and `colB` for each row in a ClickHouse table and sets `colC` value to `1` if arrays are equal, `0` if arrays are not equal?

For example:

```
colA                             |  colB                            | colC
---------------------------------|----------------------------------|-----
{555,571,701,707,741,1470,4965}  |  {555,571,701,707,741,1470,4965} |1
{555,571,701,707,741,1470,4965}  |  {555,571,701,707,741,1470,4964} |0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked the same question at [ClickHouse Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/clickhouse) and got this [answer](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/clickhouse/W4J8Jm6KwO0/LtQrE7_PGgAJ) from     Denis Zhuravlev:

In the latest version of CH 18.1.0, 2018-07-23  [(#2026)](https://github.com/yandex/ClickHouse/issues/2026):

```
select [111,222] A,  [111,222] B, [111,333] C, A=B ab, A=C ac
```

results in

```
┌─A─────────┬─B─────────┬─C─────────┬─ab─┬─ac─┐
│ [111,222] │ [111,222] │ [111,333] │  1 │  0 │
└───────────┴───────────┴───────────┴────┴────┘
```

Before 18.1.0 you can use lambdas or something:

```
SELECT 
   NOT has(groupArray(A = B), 0) ab
  ,NOT has(groupArray(A = C), 0) ac
  FROM
    (
      SELECT
         [111,222] A
        ,[111,222] B
        ,[111,333] C
    )
    ARRAY JOIN
         A
        ,B
        ,C 


┌─ab─┬─ac─┐
│  1 │  0 │
└────┴────┘
```

Answer (score 1):

I think equal works now 20.3.5.21

```
Cloud10 :) SELECT [2,1] = [1,2]

SELECT [2, 1] = [1, 2]

┌─equals([2, 1], [1, 2])─┐
│                      0 │
└────────────────────────┘

1 rows in set. Elapsed: 0.003 sec. 

Cloud10 :) SELECT [2,1] = [2,1]

SELECT [2, 1] = [2, 1]

┌─equals([2, 1], [2, 1])─┐
│                      1 │
└────────────────────────┘

1 rows in set. Elapsed: 0.003 sec.
```